# Is creating an explicit or implicit operator for a SecureString to string conversion possible?

Tags: c#, syntax, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, accessor

I have performed some research on a variety of conversion methods, and have arrived on the usage of `explicit` or `implicit operators`.

Noting that `System.Security.SecureString` is a `sealed` class (it can not be inherited from), is it possible to write an `explicit` or `implicit operator` that is able to perform conversion between a `System.Security.SecureString` and a `System.String` (utilizing the methodology [described here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549109/Working-with-SecureString)).

For instance, I do know [you must write the `operator` in a (partial) class of the object being converted](http://weblogs.asp.net/bryansampica/archive/2010/01/07/custom-explicit-and-implicit-operators-in-c.aspx).  Therefore, I figured the best way to do this was to inherit the class, and write the necessary `operators`.

Is it possible to a) perform a conversion using an `explicit` or `implicit operator` for a `System.Security.SecureString` to a `System.String`, b) perform a conversion of a class object who's class is `sealed`?

If not, is there another method outside of utilizing a class method, that will perform the conversion?

Please provide a pragmatic answer assuming I am a consumer of Microsoft's products.

Comment: Can you consider using extension methods?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: There are no extension *operators*. The design team considered them for C# 4 but they did not make the bar.

Comment: @EricLippert I didn't mean it is possible using extension methods. I suggested another option is use extension methods :)

Comment: You can use a sort of bridge class to convert between the twp types but is a little strange.

Comment: I am confused by your clarification. What constitutes a *pragmatic* answer to a yes-or-no question? You have asked four yes-or-no questions; the answer to all four is "no", provided that you do not have the source code for the class in question. If you want a more pragmatic answer than *no* then *ask a different question*.

Comment: @Eric, what he means by a pragmatic answer is a useful one that eg offers suggestions on how to work around the problem. Sarcastic, unhelpful answers, such as yours, therefore are not pragmatic. Of course I fully expect this comment to be deleted just like the last one that explained this was deleted.

Comment: @David Arno: If the answer is no, its not possible, then what added information is going to be helpful exactly? Its obvious that who asked the question knows how to convert a `SecureString` to `System.String` because he's posted a link that shows how to do it in his own question so there is no added value showing him something he already knows. So I am not really sure what the issue is here. What he's asking is not possible and there is not much more to it.

Comment: @InBetween, Please see my own answer.

Comment: @DavidArno: My answer is neither unhelpful nor sarcastic; it is an honest attempt to accurately answer the question that was asked. As you note in your correct answer, *there is no problem to be worked around here*. Rather: attempting to add the sort of functionality that the original poster wants is *undermining a security feature*.

Comment: @David Arno: I'm missing the point. Your answer is correct but it's not a solution to what the poster has asked. It just reinforces what has already been said: if you don't own the code you can't really do much about the issue.

Comment: Even writing a function which does this is a bad idea. The whole idea behind `SecureString` is keeping data out of immutable (and thus inwipable) datastructures like `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been discussed elsewhere, the simple answer to your original question is no, it's not possible to add an operator to SecureString to do anything as it's sealed.

The answer to "(b) perform a conversion of a class object who's class is sealed" is more complex.

What you can do is create your own `struct`, eg called EncryptedString that has a `SecureString` as a `private` field. You are then free to add any `SecureString` <-> `string` conversion and comparison operators and methods to that `struct` to meet your needs. That isn't strictly speaking perform[ing] a conversion of a class object, instead it is composing a new `type` to meet your needs. As the saying goes "Composition over inheritance" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), so actually this approach both meets your needs and is seen as OO "best practice".

**Now for the disclaimer:**

The whole point of `SecureString` is that, unlike `string`, it is secure. If you start converting a `SecureString` to a `string` (or allowing a `SecureString` to be created from a `string`), you'll undermine the whole point of the class.

So if you need to do comparisons, please use `Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR()` and `Marshal.StringToBSTR()` to convert the two to `BSTR structures`, compare them, wipe the memory and free it, or some similar mechanism to minimize the chances of compromising the security of `SecureStrings`.

Comment: Thank very much for the details and mentioning the `Marshal` methods.  I will have to look closer into securely clearing a string, including speeding up the garbage collection (I assume?).  I am currently relying on the class in the original, taking the string from `console.read()`, storing as a `securestring`, later converting into a `string`, and inserting into `WebCredentials()` (this is for `EWS API`), then _immediately_ after: `string = ""` and `string = null`.  I assume that this will not only clear the pointer, but also the original location in RAM?  I am not comparing the password.

Answer (score 8):

> Noting that `System.Security.SecureString` is a sealed class, is it possible to write an explicit or implicit operator that is able to perform conversion between a `System.Security.SecureString` and a `System.String`?

Yes, **if you are a member of the Base Class Library team** you can do so. Of course, doing so is a bad idea.

If you are not a member of the BCL team then no. You need to be able to change the source code of one of the two classes.

Comment: I've updated the original question with "Please provide a pragmatic answer assuming I am a consumer of Microsoft's products."

Comment: @mbrownnyc That doesn't change the answer at all.  Members of the BCL team are also usually consumers of microsoft products.  Being such a consumer doesn't mean you're *not* a member of the BCL team.  Why do you have such a problem with the answer anyway; it tells you *exactly* what you need to know, in the most correct way possible.

Comment: Sorry, for clarity added another question: "If not, is there another method outside of utilizing a class method, that will perform the conversion?"  This is a tough one to consider.  I'll leave this dude open for a bit, and see if I get anything more creative than your general (and correct) "No."  Yes, we can argue about /this/ being a good idea (meta), but keeping it simple, any other ideas for a pragmatic solution?

Comment: +1 - this is answer to title of the question - you can't extend other class with operators unless you are owner of the code. @mbrownnyc - if you looking for just a sample to convert `SecureString` to `String` your question is very bad for so as it can be found by search like http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+securestring+to+string - i.e. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fpintos/archive/2009/06/12/how-to-properly-convert-securestring-to-string.aspx

Comment: Alexei: If you re-read the question, you will see I have located a method.  For this specific instance, I am utilizing [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) and confirming to the style of utilizing accessors for the parsed options. I am a novice, so I performed some research to try to ask the right question(s).  This is one of those questions, but clearly the wrong one.  This is a place with people who want to give right answers, clearly, maybe less about people who want to give helpful answers. One can hope for the latter.